# Is it possible to create or change acroform fields size and name with pdfbox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf with acroform field with such kind of area where are many acroforms fields, separated by a colon in the name.

[image: current situation]

now I want to change this so that it looks like this

[image: desired situation]

I want remove all the fields, and have instead a field which has a size which covers all the single fields.

Is this possible with pdfbox? If someone has an example would be great.
Thanks

Comment: It is not clear if your question is either about `itext` or about `pdfbox`. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: It is possible. But you should also describe the behaviour of the new field, not merely the appearance.

Comment: I have found an example how to create a field with pdfbox here https://carbonrider.github.io/pdfbox_tutorial/pdf_new_form.html I think I can solve this problem with this knowledge

Comment: Why not use Adobe Acrobat for this? It might be possible with pdfbox programmatically but would be more work than just using a form editor. mkl has an answer somewhere about removing fields (it isn't part of the API). Enlarging a field would be easier, just change the rectangle.

Comment: Because of legacy code my application is confronted with a lot of such pdfs. its no option to do this with acrobat ... I found mkl's sample and could solve my problem. Now the fields will be removed and a new one will be generated.

Comment: @AlPhaba then consider removing this question, and upvote the answer that helped you, to avoid orphans.